# How to store HTML Form Input value to variable?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

So I have this code. The HTML is a form, and you can enter in data and submit.
Is there any way upon submit that I can store that data, and use the  tag to send 
the data in a URL to my endpoint to process properly?

Im using python and flask if you were curious. Thats why the url_for is there.

The endpoint is

```python
@app.route('/buy/<string:passed_symbol>/<string:passed_shares>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

```html
<form method="get" action="/buy">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="symbol"
    id="buySymbol" placeholder="Stock" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" type="text"
    id="buyShares" placeholder="Number of Shares" name="shares" />
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><a href="{{ url_for('buy', passed_symbol=symbol, passed_shares=shares) }}">Buy Stocks</a></button>
</form>
```

Comment: If you add an listener on the form for the submit event, the handler function will be executed before the form is submited. Now what do you mean by "store the data" ? When the form is submited a new page is loaded, if you want to have access to the data previously stored you need to use [´localSorage´](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I just parsed the data on the request to /buy by using request.form.get('id')

Answer (score 0):

By default, GET request response will be HTML formatted. if you want response in different format, use methods like `.text` or `.json()` from json module

Answer (score 0):

**Call a function on submit, get the values and then make call to the url as below:**

If you want to use Jquery use this:

```
$("#form").submit( function() {
var buySymbol= $('#buySymbol').val();
var buyShares= $('#buyShares').val();
// use the 'buySymbol' & 'buyShares' variables as needed here:
// $.post('url...', { buySymbol: buySymbol, buyShares: buyShares});
});
```

If you want to use Javascript use this:

```
function SubmitForm() {
var buySymbol= document.getElementById('buySymbol').value;
var buyShares= document.getElementById('buyShares').value;
// use the 'buySymbol' & 'buyShares' variables as needed here:
// $.post('url...', { buySymbol: buySymbol, buyShares: buyShares});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. used

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    passed_symbol = request.form.get('symbol')
    passed_shares = request.form.get('shares')
```

Answer (score 0):

function submet()=>{

```
let val1 = document.querySelector('.form-control"')[0].value;

   let val2 =  document.querySelector('form-control')[1].value;
```

console.log(val1 ,val2 );
};